# How to refresh regedit using c++?

Tags: c++, regedit

I am using simple `system()` call to change the hex value of USBSTOR for disable USB. But, it does not changes hex value without refreshing registry editor (Press f5 under view) manually. Could anyone help me do through programatically? Code snippet below.

```
int main()
{
    system("reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\USBSTOR \/v Start \/t REG_DWORD \/d 4 \/f");

    return 0;
}
```

I am using Visual Studio for this.

Comment: I think the value is actually being changed immediately, however, I doubt that the regedit program is adjusted to do dynamic refreshes. I also don't think there is a way to manipulate regedit in order to refresh via C++. (I hope I didn't misunderstand your question)

Comment: Yes, you may right. Is there a way I can use through Virtual-key codes for F5 VK_F5/0x74 (Constant/value) in VC++ for registry editor only?

Comment: Do you mean that your program could simulate pressing F5 to trigger a refresh? That could actually work in my opinion, however, you have to ensure the right window is currently focused in order not to throw the F5 into the wild

Comment: Why do you care if the change shows up the registry editor application? It's applied to the registry, that should be good enough. Of course, you're doing it wrong. If you're writing an application, you should be calling the documented APIs for editing the contents of the registry.